# express returns Cannot GET /home

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, swagger-node-express

I was trying to make real time chat application for that I used node express server and redis with Laravel.

Here is my server.js code

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(8000);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("client connected");
  var redisClient = redis.createClient();
  redisClient.subscribe('message');

  redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {
    console.log("mew message add in queue "+ data['message'] + " channel");
    socket.emit(channel, data);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    redisClient.quit();
  });

});
```

After I logged in when i go in /home route I see the following Error :

```
Cannot GET /home
```

Here is the home.blade.php code :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #messages{
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 300px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        overflow: scroll;
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
<div class="container spark-screen">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Chat Message Module</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8" >
                      <div id="messages" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8" >
                            <form action="sendmessage" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" >
                                <input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" >
                                <textarea class="form-control msg"></textarea>
                                <br/>
                                <input type="button" value="Send" class="btn btn-success send-msg">
                            </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(data.user);
        $( "#messages" ).append( "<strong>"+data.user+":</strong><p>"+data.message+"</p>" );
      });
    $(".send-msg").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
        var user = $("input[name='user']").val();
        var msg = $(".msg").val();
        if(msg != ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{!! URL::to("sendmessage") !!}',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {'_token':token,'message':msg,'user':user},
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $(".msg").val('');
                }
            });
        }else{
            alert("Please Add Message.");
        }
    })
</script>
@endsection
```

I started my project on 8000 port..Can anyone help me to find out what's the Error here?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a route `/home` in your express app. You need to [add a route](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) to your application so it knows to handle all `GET` requests to `/home`

Add the below route to `server.js`

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

// Handle GET requests to /home
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  // handle request, respond accordingly
});

server.listen(8000);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("client connected");
  var redisClient = redis.createClient();
  redisClient.subscribe('message');

  redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {
    console.log("mew message add in queue "+ data['message'] + " channel");
    socket.emit(channel, data);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    redisClient.quit();
  });

});
```

Comment: I remove the `io.on('connection', function (socket)` and replace with `app.get('/home', (req, res) => {` But I got another error like `ReferenceError: socket is not defined`

Comment: @Hola I never said remove the socket related code, I just said to add the route definition in the answer.